# without removing source file annotations verify code coverage unit testing

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

Every time I check test coverage with Jacoco, I need to comment/remove annotations from my source files.

Suppose I have a class with Spring annotations, I need to comment them. Only then, I can see the correct coverage. Otherwise, it shows wrong coverage.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method3", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody 
public String method3() {
    return "method3";
}
```

Let's say this is a method in a controller class. I want to write a JUnit test for it. When I check coverage while keeping the annotations it gives the wrong result.

If I remove the annotations from the method it will show the correct coverage.

How can I get correct coverage without removing the annotation?

Comment: Which coverage tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Jacoco. http://www.eclemma.org

Comment: Can you also give us a small example to reproduce?

Comment: Please add this to your question...